# Problem with grouping

Tags: c#, devexpress

I have the following code (DevExpress component):

```
dgvDisplayDictionary.DataSource = DataAccessor.GetAllRecords();

gvDisplay.BeginSort();
gvDisplay.ClearGrouping();
gvDisplay.Columns[0].GroupInterval = ColumnGroupInterval.Alphabetical;
gvDisplay.Columns[0].GroupIndex = 0;
gvDisplay.EndSort();
```

I get the following error:

```
At least one object must implement IComparable.
```

My class binding to `gvDisplay`:

```
public class NormDocCost:AbstractDisplayDictionary.
    {            
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }            
        public virtual DocumentFormat DocumentFormat { get; set; }            
        public virtual Translate Translate { get; set; }
        public virtual int NdcId { get; set; }           
        public virtual int PageStart { get; set; }         
        public virtual int PageEnd { get; set; }          
        public virtual double Cost { get; set; }            
        public virtual DateTime? DateFrom { get; set; }            
        public virtual DateTime? DateTo { get; set; }
   }
```

I have trying to write this code, but not works:

```
public int CompareTo(object other)
        {
            var obj = (NormDocCost)other;
            if(obj.Category.Id == Category.Id)
            {
                return this.Category.NameRu.CompareTo(obj.Category.NameRu);
            }
            return obj.Category.Id.CompareTo(Category.Id);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

When the grid groups records, it first sorts them and then only create groups based on the rows with the same values in group columns.  So, I tend to think that the first column is bound to the Categbory field.  What is the type of it?  I think that the grid cannot compare values of this field and thus this exception is raised.

Comment: Yes, I written CompareTo in Category class and now works. But not like I want. anyway it's other problem.